# How can a Muslim know if they are a hypocrite or a sinner?

Tags: practical-islam, sin, munafiq

I have been praying and reading the Quran but I’m worried that I might be a hypocrite. I found out what that means a while ago and how bad the punishments are, and I’m scared because I fit some of its description.

Even though I pray and see myself as a Muslim, I also do a lot of bad things.

For example, I sometimes lie, get upset at my parents, talk to non-Muslim guys, and look at things online that I shouldn’t be looking at. Sometimes I get lazy to pray and do it in a hurry. I pray alone and ask for forgiveness for my sins everyday, but I know that I’ll keep doing it anyways. I feel bad and I do want to be a good Muslim, not for others but for myself and for Allah. But I’m scared now.

**Am I a hypocrite or am I just like any other Muslim who commits a sin?**

Comment: Rule of thumb: If someone is worried about being a hypocrite, he's probably not one.

Answer (score 0):

The hypocrite of a person who has not accepted Islam in the heart of the religion; But in appearance he shows himself a believer. But you are not against Islam in your heart, so you are not considered a hypocrite. So you are considered a sinner Rather, you are a Muslim who is lazy in performing your Islamic duties and customs. First, try to organize your prayers and stick to them. Because adherence to prayer leads to salvation and helps you to fight sins and temptations with more energy.
23: 1,2 - Certainly, the faithful have attained salvation —those who are humble in their prayers,

29:45 - and maintain the prayer. Indeed the prayer restrains from indecent and wrongful conduct, and the remembrance of Allah is surely greater. And Allah knows whatever [deeds] you do.

To avoid sins and mistakes in the first step, you must be really sad and sorry for committing them. And in the next step, try to cleanse yourself of evils. Ask God for help in this way. You will be rewarded for this effort to self-discipline.

https://hawzah.net/fa/Article/View/4042/%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%AA

https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D9%85%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%82

Comment: @ Can you share a daleel for "The hypocrite is a person who has not accepted Islam in the heart of the religion; But in appearance he shows himself a believer."

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

Looks like you are unable to diffirenciate between being Munafiq (hypocrite) and Fasiq (open sinner)

The Munafiqoon (hypocrites) or false Muslims are a group decried in the Quran as outward Muslims who were inwardly concealing disbelief and actively sought to undermine the Muslim community.

Hypocrisy is recognised by its Signs which are described in Quran, in Suwar like Baqara, Al-Imran, Nisa, Munafeequn, etc.

I give some of them as an example,

> **[Surat Al-Munāfiqūn (The Hypocrites) 63](https://legacy.quran.com/63/4)**
>
> 4.And when you see them, their forms please you, and if they speak, you
> listen to their speech. [They are] as if they were pieces of wood
> propped up - they think that every shout is against them. They are the
> enemy, so beware of them. May Allah destroy them; how are they
> deluded?

> **[Surat Al-Baqarah (The Cow) 2](https://legacy.quran.com/2/8-10)**
>
> 8.And of the people are some who say, "We believe in Allah and the Last Day," but they are not believers. 9.They [think to] deceive Allah
> and those who believe, but they deceive not except themselves and
> perceive [it] not. 10.In their hearts is disease, so Allah has
> increased their disease; and for them is a painful punishment because
> they [habitually] used to lie.

> **[Surat 'Āli `Imrān (Family of Imran) 3](https://legacy.quran.com/3/118-120)**
>
> 118.O you who have believed, do not take as intimates those other than yourselves, for they will not spare you [any] ruin. They wish you
> would have hardship. Hatred has already appeared from their mouths,
> and what their breasts conceal is greater. We have certainly made
> clear to you the signs, if you will use reason. 119.Here you are
> loving them but they are not loving you, while you believe in the
> Scripture - all of it. And when they meet you, they say, "We believe."
> But when they are alone, they bite their fingertips at you in rage.
> Say, "Die in your rage. Indeed, Allah is Knowing of that within the
> breasts." 120.If good touches you, it distresses them; but if harm
> strikes you, they rejoice at it. And if you are patient and fear Allah
> , their plot will not harm you at all. Indeed, Allah is encompassing
> of what they do.

Fasiq is a term which refers to someone who violates Islamic law. So they are open sinner.

See also

- [Munafiq - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munafiq)
- [Fasiq - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasiq)

There are also Hadithes about signs of hypocricy. Here are some of them,

> **[Sahih al-Bukhari 33](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:33), Narrated Abu Huraira:**
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "The signs of a hypocrite are three:
>
> 1. Whenever he speaks, he tells a lie.
> 2. Whenever he promises, he always breaks it (his promise ).
> 3. If you trust him, he proves to be dishonest. (If you keep something as a trust with him, he will not return it.)"

> **[Sahih al-Bukhari 17](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:17), Narrated Anas:**
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Love for the Ansar is a sign of faith and
> hatred for the Ansar is a sign of hypocrisy."

> **[Sahih Muslim 78](https://sunnah.com/muslim:78), Zirr reported:**
>
> 'Ali observed: By Him Who split up the seed and created something
> living, the Apostle (may peace and blessings be upon him) gave me a
> promise that no one but a believer would love me, and none but a
> hypocrite would nurse grudge against me.

> **[Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1186](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1186), Thawban narrated that:**
>
> The Prophet said: "The women who seek a Khul are hypocrites."